# Как сделать квиз на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Всем здравия! Подскажите, как реализовать вот такой квиз(если это название для него корректно)? В гугле делают квизы с вариантами ответа как на первом скрине и так весь квиз, а тут есть еще инпут range и форма для номера и мыла. Прошу вашей помощи!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в каком месте возникли затруднения... В первом `<input type="radio">` во втором `type="range"` в третьем - просто инпут. При клике на кнопку - собрать `.value` из всех инпутов и отправить куда надо, нет?)

Comment: это понятно, но как сделать так, чтобы по клику на кнопку появлялся следующий вопрос? В массив вставить верстку, а из массива с помощью innerHTML вставлять на страницу?

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров: если вопросов немного, то каждый вопрос в отдельный блок и показывать по очереди. Начнёте делать - возникнут конкретные вопросы, тогда добавите код, и Вам помогут.

Comment: @UModeL хорошо, спасибо